# Append items to existing/created keys in a dictionary

Tags: python

```
words = {'apple', 'plum', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange', 'cherry', 'quince'}

d = {}  

for x in sorted(words):  
    if x not in d:  
        d[len(x)]=x  
d[len(x)].append(x)  

print(d)  
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The goal of the program is to have a multiple keys, distinguished by word length (i.e., 4, 5, or 6 letters), that store alphabetized values:

{4: 'pear', 'plum' 5: 'apple', 'peach' 6: 'cherry', 'orange', 'quince'}

I am having issues adding items to a key. What I am currently getting as my output is (without the append line):

{4: 'plum', 5: 'peach', 6: 'quince'}

so it seems to be erasing the previous loops entry. The update and append commands are coming back with errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to create a dictionary that stores each item based on their length:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
words = {'apple', 'plum', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange', 'cherry', 'quince'} 
for word in words:
   d[len(word)].append(word)

final_data = {a:sorted(b) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{4: ['pear', 'plum'], 5: ['apple', 'peach'], 6: ['cherry', 'orange', 'quince']}
```

Also, `itertools.groupby` can be used for a shorter solution:

```
import itertools
words = {'apple', 'plum', 'pear', 'peach', 'orange', 'cherry', 'quince'} 
new_words = {a:sorted(list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(words, key=len), key=len)}
```

Output:

```
{4: ['pear', 'plum'], 5: ['apple', 'peach'], 6: ['cherry', 'orange', 'quince']}
```

Comment: Excellent use of `groupby`.  I'm not a fan of the new dictionary and new sublists created for `final_data` when sorting in place would do as in `for sublist in d.values(): sublist.sort()`.  Sorting beforehand would also work as in `for word in sorted(words):`.  (Of course it's all preference.  One nice thing about the dict comprehension is that you no longer have a `defaultdict`.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I too prefer `groupby` :) It seems, however, that some users on SO prefer `defaultdict` so I thought it best to provide a solution utilizing both.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `append` to a string; you have to make your dict values `list`s from the beginning.  You also have *two* checks, not one:

- Does the dict have any words of the current length?
- Is the given word already in the list?

Try this:

```
size = len(x)
if size not in d:  
    d[size] = [x]
else:
    d[size].append(x)
```

Comment: don't forget the `else: d[len(x)].append(x)`

Comment: Aside from the error message, another thing is that the OP is checking if `str` value of `x` is not on `d` rather than the length of `x`. This in-turn reassigns the value of `len(x)` to a new list, since `x` never exists as a key

Comment: Thanks for the extensions and code reviews.

Comment: My error -- When I added ... well, I retyped the entire list and used the wrong bookends.